# Maui Push Notification navigation if app is closed

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, maui

if i tap on a Push Notification im getting navigated to the Page i saved in the notification Data.
How can i achieve this if the App is closed? Where can i see these Data?
im using firebase
Plugin => Plugin.Firebase für IOS and ANDROID

added navigation on tapped event => if app is closed not working, if app is in background => working

Comment: Which platform does this problem occur on?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT on both platforms ios and android, if the app is closed i just get redirected to the normal main page

Comment: Since you are using nuget `Plugin.Firebase`, you can create a new issue for it [here](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues).

Comment: How your closed app detected the notification? I can't figure it out?!

Answer (score 0):

I believe on Android you also have to override `OnNewIntent` on `MainActivity` class. And handle notifications received there.

You should have something similar to this:

```cs
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CreateNotificationChannel();
        HandleNotification(this.Intent);
    }
    
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        HandleNotification(intent);
    }

    private void HandleNotification(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                if (key == "NavigateTo")
                {
                    var navigateTo = intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new PushNotificationReceived(navigateTo));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On iOS is handled at the same place so I think you only have the problem on android. Let me know if it worked or if you still have issues with ios.

hope it helps

Comment: Where can i found it on ios, and what is the class PushNotificationReceived looking like?

Comment: public class NotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new PushNotificationReceived());
    }

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
}